# Chaining individual page tests

Tags: cypress

Let's suppose I am testing a site consisting of 10 pages. On the 10th and final page, this is where a payment is made, after which the flow ends.

I want to run multiple tests on this 10th page; a visa payment, a MasterCard payment, an Amex payment etc.

Now, I could write a test spanning the entire flow, resulting in a visa payment. Then, I could copy this entire test, and tweak for a MasterCard payment etc. This obviously would be practice.

How would I set about, when testing page 10 of 10, to define pages 1 to 9 as pre-requisites, hence alleviating code duplication?

Comment: Depending on the app structure (please show), you might be able to use [checkpoints](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/cypress-talks/).

Answer (score 0):

You could exclude the test case to a function that you iterate over a set of configurations. You can also use `it(` or `describe(` and programmatically build up tests. With this approach need to write it only once and still can have some `if/else` for provider specific parts.

```
describe('Checkout', () => {
  [
    {provider: 'visa', email: 'test+visa@provider.com'},
    {provider: 'mastercard', email: 'test+mastercard@provider.com'},
    {provider: 'amex', email: 'test+amex@provider.com'},
  ].forEach((setting) => {
    it(`Provider: ${setting.provider}`, () => {
      cy.get(`button[data-provider="${setting.provider}"]`).click();
      cy.get('#email')
        .value(setting.email);
      cy.assert('something');
      cy.click('.next-step');
    });
  });
});
```